# Set data type to string so XLOOKUP will work

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having some trouble with XLOOKUP running on a calculated column:

In my source table, I have a list of phone numbers with the column type set to General, input as 1##########. These values are not calculated.

In my lookup table, I have the same list of phone numbers formatted as (NNN)NNN-NNNN, I then created a column to correctly format the phone number for lookup:

```
="1" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"(",""),")",""),"-","")," ",""),".","")
```

This correctly produces a match, that visually, appears to match my source table (C) and lookup table (F).

**Source Table**

[image: Source Table]

**Lookup Table**

[image: Lookup Table]

However, I am not seeing a match using this XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Phone Number]],'Data'!F:F,'Data'!G:G,"No Match", 0,1)
```

As a simple test, if I manually type in the exact same data into column H and change it, the XLOOKUP works.

I've tried formatting both columns as "text" and "general" with no success. Is there a way in Excel to say "Hey, this column is a string, treat it as such?"

Comment: Show it clearly, without obstructing text, because it looks like the numbers of the digits don't match. When searching, compare actual values without formatting.

Comment: To set the value in a cell to be a string regardless of cell formatting, insert an initial `'` before the value.

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly, it seems the `Phone Numbers` in the **`Source Table`** is formatted as number/general, while in the **`Lookup Table`** it is formatted as text since the additional `1` which is concatenated using `&` --> `Ampersand`.

Further investigation, you may find that, in `Excel` by default numbers are `right aligned` while texts are `left aligned` unless you have formatted the alignment, but it doesn't seems so from the screenshot, as well you have confirmed about the **`Source`** data formatting. Also when you type a number in `Excel` unless before formatted it will show as `General`.

---

**What you need to do?**

Concat an `empty string` --> `""` with `[Lookup_Value]` in the **`Source Table`** while applying the formula just like shown below, which should work for you:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G4</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(F4&"",B4:B8,C4:C8,"No Match",0,1)
```

---

The above can also be written as :

```
=XLOOKUP(F4:F5&"",B4:B8,C4:C8,"No Match",0,1)
```

---

In context of the OP, the formula will be as :

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Phone Number]]&"",'Data'!F:F,'Data'!G:G,"No Match", 0,1)
```

---

Also, if you have access to `MS365`, I will highly suggest you to use the following formula for the `Person Account Mobile` instead of the multiple `SUBSTITUTE()` function in the **`Lookup_Table`**

[image]

---

```
=1&CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A4,{"(",")","-"," ","."},,1))
```

---

If a `double unary` --> `--` or `1` is multiplied or divided or `0` is added to the formula above then the `[Lookup_Value]` in `XLOOKUP()` wont require to contact and empty string

---

**Note:** The phone numbers shown are fake randomly created, also please change the reference and ranges as per your suit.

---

Comment: Sore mailbox & breakable pollution, nice =)